# Add Four buttons in a panel in MFC Ribbon

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2013, ribbon-control

I want to add 4 navigation button in a panel. For Go to First page , previous page, next page, last page [<< < >> >]. I want these buttons in a row but MFC automatically put them in a column. Is there a work around to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you associate these buttons with **large** (32x32) images? Otherwise, the MFC Ribbon is always trying to put them into the column. In addition, you've to call SetAlwaysLargeImage method for each button to prevent button size decreasing when the frame is being resized.

Regards,
Rob